# Equivalence class help

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have a question that goes as follows:
Let d be a positive integer. Define the relation Rho on the integers Z as follows: for all m,n element of the integers.

m rho n if and only if d|(m-n)
Prove that rho is an equivalence relation. Then list its equivalence classes.

Now the first d that comes to mind is 1, so I proved it was an equivalence relation as follows:

Reflexive: m rho m <=> d|m-m

Symmetric: m rho n <=> d|m-n => d|n-m with n-m = -(m-n) <=> n rho m

Transitive: k is an element of integers:
m rho n and n rho k => d|m-n & d|n-k => d|(m-n) + (n-k) => d|m-k => m rho k

I am unsure if this is a sufficient proof or if my logic holds. However I can't think of any equivalence classes for this as d can vary. If d was 7 for example I would think equivalence classes would be 1 = {...,-13,-6,1,8,15,...}, 2 = {...,-12,-5,2,9,15,...} etc...

Does this relation have equivalence classes and I am missing something or?

Comment: You're on track. As Henry noted below, you have a different equivalence relation for each $d$ you select. Your example for $d=7$ is a perfectly good instance.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! As a matter of courtesy, it's a good idea to wait until you've collected a few answers and then if one seemed to be helpful, reward the answerer by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. By "accepting" an answer that way, the answerer will gain reputation points, not to mention that your future questions will be more likely to get responses.

Comment: Unfortunately until I receive 15 reputation, I am unable to reward any answerer apparently. Otherwise I surely would!

In regards to the original question, I can't seem to pin down the concept of equivalence classes for this question. Due to the varying nature of d, mentally it would either have none, or it would have a set for each d. Should I be thinking about an equation that encompasses all sets of equivalence classes?

Comment: Don't think of all sets of equivalence classes; just concentrate on one for each $d$. I can't imagine any meaningful way to extend this to *all* $d$. p.s. You can always accept an answer, no matter what reputation you had. Just click on the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different relation for each $d$. What is being asked is "for all $d$, is the corresponding relation an equivalence relation?"

As for your proof, it is correct, but you may want to be clearer with some of the steps, depending on how familiar the intended audience is with divisibility.

Comment: In determining the equivalence classes, will it be possible for me to reduce the classes to an equation? Otherwise it seems that due to the varying nature of d, there will be infinite classes.

Also just a functionality of stack-exchange question. Do questions(such as the initial one I posed above) get buried after a short amount of time, meaning essentially no-one new will find them, or do they get bumped with every post?

Comment: For each $d$, there is a finite number of equivalence classes. Writing a specific one is relatively easy: $\overline{a} = \{ a + nd \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Can you show there are only $d$ classes (once you fix $d$)? Unless $d = 0$, in which case, the classes are just $\overline{a} = \{a\}$, so there's infinitely many.